# Radio Button in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I want to know if there's a radio button in pygame or a module of it.
I'm making a questions game which requires radio buttons.

Comment: See [_GUIs with pygame_](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui) or [searching with Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=pygame+GUI+module&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#newwindow=1&hl=en&as_qdr=all&q=pygame+%22radio+button%22).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know how you feel man, I needed some radio buttons to. I have, however, been working on a checkbox in pygame. I'll post the code below if you want to use it:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()


class Checkbox:
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, color=(230, 230, 230), caption="", outline_color=(0, 0, 0),
                 check_color=(0, 0, 0), font_size=22, font_color=(0, 0, 0), text_offset=(28, 1)):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.caption = caption
        self.oc = outline_color
        self.cc = check_color
        self.fs = font_size
        self.fc = font_color
        self.to = text_offset
        # checkbox object
        self.checkbox_obj = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, 12, 12)
        self.checkbox_outline = self.checkbox_obj.copy()
        # variables to test the different states of the checkbox
        self.checked = False
        self.active = False
        self.unchecked = True
        self.click = False

    def _draw_button_text(self):
        self.font = pg.font.Font(None, self.fs)
        self.font_surf = self.font.render(self.caption, True, self.fc)
        w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)
        self.font_pos = (self.x + 12 / 2 - w / 2 + self.to[0], self.y + 12 / 2 - h / 2 + self.to[1])
        self.surface.blit(self.font_surf, self.font_pos)

    def render_checkbox(self):
        if self.checked:
            pg.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
            pg.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
            pg.draw.circle(self.surface, self.cc, (self.x + 6, self.y + 6), 4)

        elif self.unchecked:
            pg.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
            pg.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
        self._draw_button_text()

    def _update(self, event_object):
        x, y = event_object.pos
        # self.x, self.y, 12, 12
        px, py, w, h = self.checkbox_obj  # getting check box dimensions
        if px < x < px + w and px < x < px + w:
            self.active = True
        else:
            self.active = False

    def _mouse_up(self):
            if self.active and not self.checked and self.click:
                    self.checked = True
            elif self.checked:
                self.checked = False
                self.unchecked = True

            if self.click is True and self.active is False:
                if self.checked:
                    self.checked = True
                if self.unchecked:
                    self.unchecked = True
                self.active = False

    def update_checkbox(self, event_object):
        if event_object.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.click = True
            # self._mouse_down()
        if event_object.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            self._mouse_up()
        if event_object.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            self._update(event_object)

    def is_checked(self):
        if self.checked is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_unchecked(self):
        if self.checked is False:
            return True
        else:
        return False
```

A few **caveats** though.
There are still some bugs to be worked out in the code, one of which is that you can un-check the checkbox without hovering over it. And at the moment they don't function like radio buttons. And one more thing. I coded all of this in python 3.5. sorry

That being said, You're very much welcome to use the code to began to build your own radio buttons. Just make sure you show me what you come up with ;).

Here is an example of how to use the module:

```
import checkbox
import pygame as pg

def main():
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 600
    display = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    chkbox = checkbox.Checkbox(display, 400, 400)

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
                pg.quit()
                quit()
            chkbox.update_checkbox(event)

        display.fill((200, 200, 200))
        chkbox.render_checkbox()
        pg.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the checkbox.py to handle multiple checkboxes:

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()

class Checkbox:
def __init__(self, surface, x, y, idnum, color=(230, 230, 230), caption="", 
outline_color=(0, 0, 0),
             check_color=(0, 0, 0), font_size=22, font_color=(0, 0, 0), 
text_offset=(28, 1), font='Ariel Black'):
    self.surface = surface
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.color = color
    self.caption = caption
    self.oc = outline_color
    self.cc = check_color
    self.fs = font_size
    self.fc = font_color
    self.to = text_offset
    self.ft = font

    #identification for removal and reorginazation
    self.idnum = idnum

    # checkbox object
    self.checkbox_obj = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 12, 12)
    self.checkbox_outline = self.checkbox_obj.copy()

    # variables to test the different states of the checkbox
    self.checked = False

def _draw_button_text(self):
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.ft, self.fs)
    self.font_surf = self.font.render(self.caption, True, self.fc)
    w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)
    self.font_pos = (self.x + self.to[0], self.y + 12 / 2 - h / 2 + 
    self.to[1])
    self.surface.blit(self.font_surf, self.font_pos)

def render_checkbox(self):
    if self.checked:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.cc, (self.x + 6, self.y + 6), 4)

    elif not self.checked:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
    self._draw_button_text()

def _update(self, event_object):
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    px, py, w, h = self.checkbox_obj
    if px < x < px + w and py < y < py + w:
        if self.checked:
            self.checked = False
        else:
            self.checked = True
        print(str(self.caption)+' toggle '+str(self.checked))

def update_checkbox(self, event_object):
    if event_object.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        self.click = True
        self._update(event_object)
```

Here is an example of main.py to implement multiple checkboxes:

```
import sys, pygame
import checkbox
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.width=int(960)
        self.height=int(1080)
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode([self.width,self.height])
        my_outline_color = (78, 137, 202)
        my_check_color = (22, 61, 105)
        my_font_size = 25
        my_font_color = (39, 111, 191)
        my_text_offset = (28, 1)
        my_font = "Open Sans"

        self.boxes=[]
        self.idnum = 1

        self.add_checkbox(self.screen, self.get_box_x(), self.get_box_y(self.idnum), caption="checkbox",
            outline_color=my_outline_color, check_color=my_check_color, font_size=my_font_size, font_color=my_font_color,
            text_offset=my_text_offset, font=my_font)

        self.add_checkbox(self.screen, self.get_box_x(), self.get_box_y(self.idnum), caption="checkbox for something",
            outline_color=my_outline_color, check_color=my_check_color, font_size=my_font_size, font_color=my_font_color,
            text_offset=my_text_offset, font=my_font)

        self.add_checkbox(self.screen, self.get_box_x(), self.get_box_y(self.idnum), caption="checkbox for something else",
            outline_color=my_outline_color, check_color=my_check_color, font_size=my_font_size, font_color=my_font_color,
            text_offset=my_text_offset, font=my_font)

    def add_checkbox(self, surface, x, y, color=(230, 230, 230), caption="", outline_color=(0, 0, 0),
                 check_color=(0, 0, 0), font_size=22, font_color=(0, 0, 0), text_offset=(28, 1), font='Ariel Black'):
        self.idnum+=1

        box = checkbox.Checkbox(self.screen, x, y, self.idnum, color, caption,
            outline_color, check_color, font_size, font_color, text_offset, font)

        self.boxes.append(box)

    #Not working
    def remove_checkbox(self, id_to_remove):
        for box in self.boxes:
            if box.idnum == id_to_remove:
                self.boxes.remove(box)
        self.idnum-=1

    def get_box_x(self):
        return 50

    def get_box_y(self, y):
        return y*30

    def start(self):
        input_box = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 140, 32)
        while self.running:
            ev = pygame.event.get()
            for event in ev:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    for box in self.boxes:
                        box.update_checkbox(event)

                    #debugging
                    for box in self.boxes:
                        if box.checked:
                            print(str(box.caption)+ " is checked")
                        if not box.checked:
                            print(str(box.caption)+ " is not checked")

            #draw to screen
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, pygame.Color(255, 255, 255), [0,0,self.width,self.height])

            for box in self.boxes:
                box.render_checkbox()

            #refresh
            pygame.display.flip()

window = Window()
window.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some modification to change the order: 'text' then 'checkbox':

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()

class ui_Checkbox:
   def __init__(self, surface, x, y, idnum, color=(230, 230, 230), caption="", outline_color=(0, 0, 0), check_color=(0, 0, 0), font_size=22,\
    font_color=(0, 0, 0), text_offset=(28, 1), font='Ariel Black', isChecked=False):
    self.surface = surface
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.color = color
    self.caption = caption
    self.oc = outline_color
    self.cc = check_color
    self.fs = font_size
    self.fc = font_color
    self.to = text_offset
    self.ft = font

    #identification for removal and reorginazation
    self.idnum = idnum

    # checkbox object
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.ft, self.fs)
    self.font_surf = self.font.render(self.caption, True, self.fc)
    w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)

    self.checkbox_obj = pygame.Rect(self.x + w + 24, self.y + 4, 12, 12)
    self.checkbox_outline = self.checkbox_obj.copy()

    # variables to test the different states of the checkbox
    self.checked = isChecked

def _draw_button_text(self):
    w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)
    self.font_pos = (self.x, self.y + 12 / 2 - h / 2 + self.to[1])
    self.surface.blit(self.font_surf, self.font_pos)

def render_checkbox(self):
    self._draw_button_text()
    if self.checked:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
        w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.cc, (self.x + w + 30, self.y + 10), 4)
    elif not self.checked:
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)



def _update(self, event_object):
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    px, py, w, h = self.checkbox_obj
    if px < x < px + w and py < y < py + w:
        if self.checked:
            self.checked = False
        else:
            self.checked = True

def update_checkbox(self, event_object):
    if event_object.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        self.click = True
        self._update(event_object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that is based on @[Christian Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6640099/christian-dean)'s answer.
The only difference is that only one button can be selected at a time.
I achieved this by testing if a button is selected/clicked (`button.checked` is set to `True`), then the other buttons will be automatically unselected (`buttons.checked` is set to `False`).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()

class Checkbox:
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, idnum, color=(230, 230, 230),
        caption="", outline_color=(0, 0, 0), check_color=(0, 0, 0),
        font_size=22, font_color=(0, 0, 0), 
    text_offset=(28, 1), font='Ariel Black'):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.caption = caption
        self.oc = outline_color
        self.cc = check_color
        self.fs = font_size
        self.fc = font_color
        self.to = text_offset
        self.ft = font

        #identification for removal and reorginazation
        self.idnum = idnum

        # checkbox object
        self.checkbox_obj = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 12, 12)
        self.checkbox_outline = self.checkbox_obj.copy()

        # variables to test the different states of the checkbox
        self.checked = False

    def _draw_button_text(self):
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.ft, self.fs)
        self.font_surf = self.font.render(self.caption, True, self.fc)
        w, h = self.font.size(self.caption)
        self.font_pos = (self.x + self.to[0], self.y + 12 / 2 - h / 2 + 
        self.to[1])
        self.surface.blit(self.font_surf, self.font_pos)

    def render_checkbox(self):
        if self.checked:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
            pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.cc, (self.x + 6, self.y + 6), 4)

        elif not self.checked:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.checkbox_obj)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.oc, self.checkbox_outline, 1)
        self._draw_button_text()

    def _update(self, event_object):
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        px, py, w, h = self.checkbox_obj
        if px < x < px + w and py < y < py + w:
            if self.checked:
                self.checked = False
            else:
                self.checked = True

    def update_checkbox(self, event_object):
        if event_object.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.click = True
            self._update(event_object)
            
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    boxes = []
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
    button = Checkbox(screen, 200, 200, 0, caption='button1')
    button2 = Checkbox(screen, 200, 250, 1, caption='button2')
    button3 = Checkbox(screen, 200, 300, 2, caption='button3')
    boxes.append(button)
    boxes.append(button2)
    boxes.append(button3)
    screen.fill((255, 255 ,255))
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:    
                for box in boxes:
                    box.update_checkbox(event)
                    if box.checked is True:
                        for b in boxes:
                            if b != box:
                                b.checked = False
        for box in boxes:
            box.render_checkbox()
               
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
```